# How to set the precision for double return type method

Tags: java, int, double

Below is the double return type function and i would like to get the answer with precision of 2 zeros. My current answer is coming out to be `-4.5`. Whereas i want it to be `-4.50`. Any kind of help will be really appreciated

```
public double getAmount(){
        double ftotal = car.hello();

        return Math.round(ftotal * 100)/100.0d;
}
```

Comment: `double`s are **numbers**. Numerically, -4.5 and -4.50 are exactly the same thing. Having zeros at the end is a **representation** thing (e.g.: formatting, strings). That said, `BigDecimal` has the concept of scale.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is a Double so you can't pad 0s to a Double.  
So you must format the returned value to create a string, like:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
String number = formatter.format(getTotal());     
System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer below code -

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Decimal2{

    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double input = 62.123454;
        System.out.println("double : " + df2.format(input));

    }
}
```